# Attach debugger to Strapi server

Tags: strapi

How to start Strapi with `--inspect=0.0.0.0:9229` parameter or any other way to attach the debugger to my server?

This is how I could manage that with alpha version but `server.js` has been removed since beta:

package.json -> scripts

```
 "debug": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 server.js"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Never mind,

```
node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 ./node_modules/.bin/strapi dev
```

does the trick.

Comment: for me that did not work, however, this did: `node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 ./node_modules/strapi/bin/strapi develop`

Comment: In Strapi 4.8, I had to do `node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 ./node_modules/@strapi/strapi/bin/strapi develop` as the binary path had changed.

Answer (score 1):

```
node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 ~/path/to/project/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/bin/strapi develop
```